# How to send custom data in blogger json feed?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, blogger

How can I get custom data of my blogger post ?

In a blogger template, we can get some several data's from JSON link, like `https://yourblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results=500`. In this way we can even get the all contents inside a post body. I mean what we enter / write inside post editor/post HTML editor, which shows in the post page contents.

But what if we want to show some data's that we don't write in post-body/post editor, but a part of a post. For example, if I use `post-views` plugin for my blogger websites that will count post views number, or `estimated reading time`. These are not Written in post editor, but simple way for each posts to show post views or reading time. How can we send these data's in backend or in Blogger JSON Data...?

There's no way to write extra codes to write codes inside `<data:post.body/>` tag, and this tag sends data to JSON feed  Is there any Opportunity to create custom layout data tags for my template ? Like `<data:post.readingTime/>`  or  `<data:post.postViews/>`

What's the solution for this if I want these data ?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible ever.